# It is me who am to blame. It is I who am to blame

Tags: personal-pronouns

1. It is **me** who am to blame.
2. It is **I** who am to blame.

Which one is correct here?
I am bewildered about these two sentences.

Comment: What makes you think the number of correct sentences is 1 rather than 0 or 2?

Comment: Related: [“It was me” or “It was I”](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/68966/3281).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have got to remember one rule:

> When who refers to a personal pronoun (I, you, he, she, we, they), it takes the verb that agrees with that pronoun.([See Source](https://www.grammarbook.com/grammar/pronoun.asp))

Examples :

> It is **I** who **am sorry**.(*I am sorry*)
>
> It is **you** who **are responsible**.(*You are responsible*)
>
> It is **we** who **are winning the bet**.(*We are winning the bet*)
>
> It is **they** who **have been watching TV since morning**.(*They have been watching TV since morning*)

Considering the above material:

> **Correct** : It is **I** who **am to blame**.(*I am to blame*)
>
> **Incorrect** : It is I who is to blame. (*I is to blame* doesn't make sense)

Comment: Take it across the finish line and cover "me"".

Answer (score 3):

Regarding the first part of the sentence, [it's complicated](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ny18k07yMSI).

> ...so the choice between "It's me" and "It is I" is one of style. **Are you writing formal dialogue or in a formal setting? Then use "It is I"**. **But in everyday use you can use "It's me"** with impunity.

Therefore, the correct sentence would be either

> It is I who is to blame.

or

> It's me who is to blame.

*Note: In your sentence, you would say "who is to blame" instead of "who am to blame".*

Comment: What about the forms with "am"?

Comment: You wouldn't use 'am' in this context, you would use is. 'I am to blame' would be the closest use.

Comment: Still,  I am confused.

Comment: If there is "I before who we will use "am"according to I.

Comment: So the pattern used in "Our father who art in heaven" is completely archaic in Modern English? I'm a native speaker, but this question is actually one I've never been able to figure out. "It is I who **am** to blame" sounds OK to my ears, maybe a little odd, but "It is I who **is** to blame" sounds a bit odd as well.

Comment: @sumelic "Art" is a different word from "am" or "is," and would therefore carry different usage, I would think. I am pretty uneducated in the field of Middle English and how Modern English is derived from/relates to it, however. I would think it is "am" in Modern English because you're still referring to the subject of the sentence, "I." Again, not very well-versed on this specifically, though.

Comment: If you are really going formal, "It is I who am" is the most correct choice.  But I agree that "it's me who is" is much more likely in normal speech.  I'd never choose "it is I who is" because it's a weird, unsatisfying compromise between those two.

Comment: @CrazyEyes "Art" is specifically the form of "to be" that agrees with "thou."  I am/thou art/he is

Answer (score 1):

"It's I who am to blame" is correct because "I" is the subject.

Comment: This is not a good *answer* to the question, because it gives little explanation or example, but it's not *wrong*.  Although (as an AmE native speaker) I don't personally know anyone who talks like this, most people would instead say simply, "I'm to blame".