# "It is you who doesn't OR don't want this" - Stuck between 'don't' and 'does not'

Tags: verbs, pronouns, subject-verb-agreement, cleft-constructions

I got stuck while writing this in a post

> *"It is **you who does** not want ...."*

While the third person *'it'* takes 'does not', when I reveal that it is *'you'*, should I use 'don't'?

In my final version, it's 'does not'.

Comment: A related question: "**[Is “It is you who are mistaken!” correct?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/57954/is-it-is-you-who-are-mistaken-correct)**"

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["It was me" or "It was I"](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/68966/it-was-me-or-it-was-i)

Comment: Duplicate? Strange! @DamkerngT. Do you see this question duplicate with confusion for the subject/object for pronoun 'me' and 'I'?

Comment: Read my answer and you'll understand.

Comment: Where's comparing second person 'you are' and third person 'it is'? @DamkerngT. The answer talks about 'me', 'I', and 'you'. Here, the confusion is **'you are'** and '**it is** you who'

Comment: @CopperKettle yes. that is quite informative. It answered me. Thanks.

Comment: @MaulikV Have you checked my reference? -- In any case, I chose to vote to close this question because I remembered that the stock phrase of the message would be "Possible duplicate of ...". Note the word "Possible". So, this is just my opinion, and I respect other users who may or may not agree with me.

Answer (score 1):

The dominant subject here is the pronoun "who." Third person. To complicate matters even further, consider this (a notch more natural sounding than your example):

**Are you the one who does not wish to ...**

Pretty cool, isn't it?

Comment: +1, but I think you should have been more specific: "third person", *singular* although it is obvious in this case. What if it were: all of you who...?

Comment: You said 'third person'. So, it means "It is you who **don't** want.." is *incorrect?* The [top rated answer here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/57954/is-it-is-you-who-are-mistaken-correct) is something else.