# Can a verb agree with "me"

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

> He is just like me who hate/hates learning.

Hate should agree with **who** in the relative clause right? But *who is me*. Can it agree with the objective noun?

Comment: @P.E.Dant isn't the singular form for hate is hates??

Comment: @P.E.Dant Ohh, me is the first person! Thanks a lot

Comment: Now...I believe your first choice was correct. "Who" is the subject of the clause "who hates learning," so "hates" is correct. I'm well in the weeds on this one, I'm afraid. So: _He is just like me who hates learning._ I'll delete my eariler comments to prevent confusion.

Comment: Native speaker logic: If I change it to "It is I who hates learning," then "hates" sounds much better than "hate" to my ear.

Comment: @Kevin In _It is I who hates learning,_ "hates" _is_ correct. The pronoun _who_ is still the subject of the clause _who hates learning,_ and takes the third person singular form of the verb.

Comment: Related: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/68966/it-was-me-or-it-was-i

Comment: @DamkerngT. Related to comments, but not to the question, which asks about the form of the verb in the second clause, and not about the pronoun. It could not be _who **hate** learning_ unless the referent of _who_ is plural, e.g.: _They are just like us/we who **hate** learning._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either way, this is wrong - people do not use "like me who" after a copula. Searching for "is like me who" in Google yields zero results.

You can find "like me who" after nouns, as in

- A person like me who likes parties
- People like me who go to bed early

... often with a comma separating the "who" clause.

As you can see, in this quite common pattern, the verb agrees with the initial noun, and not necessarily with "me".

Answer (score -1):

It should just be:

"He is just like me, he hates learning."

Comment: A better answer would include a clear explanation. :)

Comment: Please [edit] to include an explanation of why this is correct; answers without explanation do not teach the patterns of the language well.